# Замена шорткода регулярным выражением

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, wordpress

У меня в постах осталось много шорткодов от неработающего уже плагина такого типа:
`[download#434]`

или `[download#434#nohits]`

или `[download#68#size]`

Как с помощью регулярно выражения все их перезаписать к одному виду
типа:
`[download id="68"]` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '[download#688#nohits]  as [download#34]';
$pattern = '/\[(\w+)#(\d+).*?\]/im';
$replacement = '[$1 id="$2"]';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Comment: Плохое выражение. Протестируйте на такой строке: '[download#434#23] ab [download#4]'

Comment: @ZhukovRoman, исправил ответ.

Comment: а теперь на этой: '[upload#688#nohits] as [download#34]'.

Comment: @ZhukovRoman, протестировал, все работает.

Comment: Ну если не считать, что тэг upload относится к другому плагину и менять его не надо было - то да :)

Comment: @ZhukovRoman, ну если не надо, убрать это проблем не составит, я думаю.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = preg_replace("/\[download#([0-9]+).*?]/ium", "[download id=\"$1\"]", $string);
```

где $string - строка для обработки.

Comment: Не пойму, зачем оба отвечающих модификатор `m` в регулярку запихали? P,S. В такой регулярке и не `u`, и не `i` не нужны, а 'm' тем более.

Comment: @Visman, спасибо, полностью с вами согласен. Есть ли минусы при их использовании в данном контексте?

Comment: `i` и `u` вполне могут замедлять отработку `preg_replace` (сильно зависит от версии php), `m` работает вхолостую и прямо вреда не наносит, пока кто-нибудь не посмотрит на ваши регулярки и не сделает аналогично, но и с использованием `^`, `$`.